# Метод onOptionsItemSelected.Для чего в case прописывается return true?

Tags: java, android

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header);
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.settings:
            header.setText("Вы вошли в настройки");
            Toast.makeText(this,"Settings",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.open:
            header.setText("Вы открыли ресурс");
            Toast.makeText(this,"Open",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.save:
            header.setText("Вы сохранили изменения");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `switch` реализован таким образом, что после совпадения первого `case`, выполняются все остальные `case`, пока не встретится оператор передачи управления. Обычно это `break` - выход из оператора `case`. Но встречается и `return` - выход из всего метода.

Если в данном коде заменить `return` на `break`, то выполнится еще и родительский `onOptionsItemSelected`, а это не требуется, т.к. условие уже отработано

Comment: т.е. если не будет return true, то вызов родителя onOptionsItemSelected приведет к выполнению всех case ?  Я сейчас ради эксперимента закомментировал return, и у меня при нажатии на любой пункт меню отобразились сразу 3 Toast по очереди, но TextView не изменялся

Comment: а если выполнится родительский onOptionsItemSelected,то что произойдет ?

Comment: @Влад Нужно смотреть на родительский метод. Весьма вероятно, что ничего, т.к. там будет такой же `switch` но уже по своим условиям. Но т.к. ни одно условие не будет выполнено, то метод вернет `false`. И это же значение вернет и ваш метод. Т.е. внешний код подумает, что ни один из элементов не был выбран